# Auto resize of my menu list CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, web

When I get the cursor on the `GOOGLE` button, the parent block resizes by itself. I want the grandchild elements outside the parent button.

CODE:

```css
ol {
  display: none;
}

li:hover ol {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -4.2em;
}

#shadow li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="shadow">
    <ul>
      <li style="margin-left : -2.5em">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
        <ol type="a">
          <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">google1</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">google1</a>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">YOUTUBE</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">FACEBOOK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would simply re-work the HTML structure so that the menu list isn't nested within the top-level menu "button" and then you just need to show/hide the menu list on the hovering of the top-level menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to resolve this would be to simply give the `li` elements the same height on `hover`:

```
li:hover {
  height: 18px;
}
```

This can be seen in the following example:

```css
ol {
  display: none;
}

li:hover {
  height: 18px;
}

li:hover ol {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -4.2em;
}

#shadow li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="shadow">
    <ul>
      <li style="margin-left : -2.5em">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
        <ol type="a">
          <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">google1</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">google1</a>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">YOUTUBE</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">FACEBOOK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol {
  display: none;
}

li:hover ol {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -4.2em;
}

#shadow li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="shadow">
    <ul>
      <li style="margin-left : -2.5em; height: 1em;">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
        <ol type="a">
          <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">google1</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">google1</a>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">YOUTUBE</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">FACEBOOK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
ol {
  display: none;
}

li:hover ol {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -4.2em;
}

#shadow li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="shadow">
    <ul>
      <li style="margin-left : -2.5em">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
        <ol type="a">
          <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">google1</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="http://www.google.com">google1</a>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">YOUTUBE</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">FACEBOOK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

I added a height attribute to your `li` tag.  I think that's what you were looking for.